# No thumbnails when sharing Wordpress Url on Facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress, url

I have read many other posts about this issue but I haven't found my solution. When I try to share an url on Facebook, no thumbnail is shown. My site is http://international-student-office.com

I also tried to find out the problem in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ but I receive this message: Could not retrieve data from URL.

Any who can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) to handle this. Here the code for an image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/your_img.jpg" />
```

There are many plugins for WordPress which add this to your posts / pages automatically, see: [WordPress Plugin Search "Open Graph"](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=open%20graph).
A few SEO Plugins out there should do this work too, like [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).

Another solution is to add it directly in your template by yourself, this depends a little bit of your template, but in common it should be at your *post.php* and you have to add something like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content=
    "<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>"
/>
```

for getting the post id, check the whole example at the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

Comment: What do you mean with the post id? Should I write this on each post I write? Or should I write it in header.php, functions.php or where?

Comment: In post.php or single.php, depending on your Theme. I linked an example there. With the plugins mentioned here [WordPress Plugin Search "Open Graph"](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=open%20graph) you dont't have to do this, they take your thumbnail automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for installing the FB Open Graph plugin on your wordpress website. This will solve your problem.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-facebook-open-graph-protocol/

Comment: I tried it but it don't solve my problem. I also tried other similar plugins.

Comment: @user3202108 Please try fixing the validation errors on your site. This might also affect the facebook parsing. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Finternational-student-office.com%2F2013%2F12%2Fsan-diegos-top-5-restaurants-student-experience-of-juergen-h-semester-abroad-usa%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0